# asp.net and Identity Server 3

Tags: asp.net, identityserver3

I am trying to authenticate my application with Identity Server Version 3.  But, when I do, I get an error.  Here is my code:

**Startup.Auth.vb:**

```
Partial Public Class Startup
     Public Sub ConfigureAuth(app As IAppBuilder)
              app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)
              app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions())

             app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions() With {
               .ClientId = clientId,
               .Authority = authority,
               .RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44321/",
               .Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
               .ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
               .TokenValidationParameters = New TokenValidationParameters() With {
               .ValidateIssuer = False
            },
            .Notifications = New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications() With {
                .AuthenticationFailed = AddressOf OnAuthenticationFailed
        }
        })

     End Sub
     Private Function OnAuthenticationFailed(ByVal context As AuthenticationFailedNotification(Of OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions)) As Task
        context.HandleResponse()
        context.Response.Redirect("/?errormessage=" & context.Exception.Message)
        Return Task.FromResult(0)
    End Function

end class
```

**Login Page:**

```
Protected Sub manuanSignIn(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles manualLogin.Click
    If (Not Request.IsAuthenticated) Then
        Dim newAuth As AuthenticationProperties = New AuthenticationProperties()
        newAuth.RedirectUri = "/"           
        HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(newAuth, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)

    End If
End Sub
```

The Error I get, when I attempt to login, is:

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Anyone have ideas on what is causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this fixed the issue:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```